# Is it correct to say: "out of nostalgia for [someone]"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm a bit unsure because I didn't find [that usage](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=out%20of%20nostalgia%20for&oq=out%20of%20nostalgia%20for&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3245j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on Google.

Example sentence:

> She came back to New Work out of nostalgia for Mark.

Comment: If you're searching for a phrase, you have to put quote marks around it, like "out of nostalgia for".  [There are many examples in Google Books.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=7J1EW8m_HuqmggelrKvYAw&q=%22out+of+nostalgia+for%22&oq=%22out+of+nostalgia+for%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3111.3510.0.3666.4.4.0.0.0.0.85.280.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.nbGWmkj1uCc)

Comment: @stangdon I know. But none of the examples uses a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that's absolutely fine grammatically and technically fine semantically, it's probably not the word you're looking for. Nostalgia, while it can absolutely be for a person, isn't *usually* felt for a person.

Perhaps you meant that she missed Mark? Without context we can't tell. If you're sure nostalgia is what you mean though, the sentence is fine.